# confused about self.instance in save() of child of ModelForm()

Tags: django, save, instance, modelform

The [save() documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) explains that:

> A subclass of ModelForm can accept an
>   existing model instance as the keyword
>   argument instance; if this is
>   supplied, save() will update that
>   instance. If it's not supplied, save()
>   will create a new instance of the
>   specified model

However, `self.instance` in `save()` always has an object.

So, how do I tell if the `instance` is existing or a newly created one?

Comment: Are you overriding `save()` in your subclass of `ModelForm`?  IF so, you can check the instance yourself before calling `super(MyForm, self).save( ))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check `self.instance.pk` to see if the model has previously been saved.  However, that could be unreliable in the case where you created a new instance of the model and then initialized a modelform with that instance before saving it.

Another possibility, based on the BaseModelForm source code in Django 1.2, is to check `self.instance._adding`, which will be True if the model was created and False otherwise.  However, I haven't tested this, so YMMV.

If the first option will work, I'd recommend using that rather than an undocumented feature of ModelForms--it's less likely to change in the future and probably clearer.

Comment: I think self.instance._adding may have be deprecated and removed in Django 1.3.